# Android market apps

Tags: android

I want to use some Android Market app. But in attempt to make the tablet secured device, can not use it. As all the apps has link to somewhere else thro' ads or links. How can I use the app but stop firing off of browser from that app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download an app and use it in airplane mode to turn off all wireless connections, that way it will not connect to anything to try and pull down extra ads. There may be ad's built in already though.

Comment: I am deploying tablets for a work group and do not want them to use it for anything else other than the app.

Comment: So you just want to lock it down so that they can only use that one app? It may be possible to password protect all other applications on the device (Even App Store and Browser) so that they can't access the other apps unless they have the password.

Comment: How do I password protect a browser ?

Comment: Download APP Lock from the App Store. I just downloaded it. It works great.

Comment: Yeah, APP Lock is definitely the answer you are looking for. You can select which apps to lock or lock all of the apps on your smartphone.

Comment: Exactly! It works! THANKS ! Now my manager will ask me to write that app lock :(